# 2 Submit buttons in 1 form

Tags: coldfusion

I have 2 submit buttons in my form.

```
<input type="submit" value="Save as Draft">
<input type="submit" value="Save">
```

Basically, what I want to do is when the user clicks on `Save as Draft`, it will proceed to bring all the form details to `_update.cfm` (without validating) and when the user clicks on `Save`, it will proceed to `_validate.cfm` and  then to `_update.cfm`(validating and updating the database.)

HTML:

```
<cfset tx_name = "">

<cfif isDefined("form.tx_name")>
    <cfset tx_name = form.tx_name>
</cfif>

<cfinclude template="_validate.cfm">

<cfif isDefined("form.tx_name")>
    <cfinclude template="_update.cfm">
</cfif>

<form name="something">
    <input type="text" name="tx_name" value="#tx_name#">
    <input type="submit" value="Save as Draft">
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

So basically what the above form does is that, by default, `tx_name = " "` and when user types something and submits, it will do all the validation in `_validate.cfm`  and then proceed to `_update.cfm` to update it.

This is the intended way to work when the user clicks on `Save` button. However, for `Save as Draft,` I would like it to skip the `_validate.cfm` and straight bring all the form field data to `_update.cfm`.

The following is what I tried:

Attempt 1:

Instead of having `<input type="submit" value="Save as Draft">`, I used `<input type="button" value="Save as Draft" onClick="location.href='_update.cfm';"`. And this didn't bring the form fields to `_update.cfm` and I figured out the reason, its because it is just redirecting to `_update.cfm` upon clicking the button.

So this made me think that I really need a `submit` button (to bring form data to the _update.cfm page).

But here is where I am lost as I have now 2 submit buttons. 1 of it is to work with `_validate.cfm` and the other to work without `_validate.cfm`.

So how do I go about to make `Save as Draft` not validate but update and `Save` to validate and update?

Comment: Having two submit buttons are a fundamentally bad idea.  Either radio buttons or a dropdown is a better way to get users to make a selection.

Comment: Similar topic: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/53759/form-with-both-save-and-submit-buttons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that you have to add name for the two submit buttons. And using that name we can prevent the _validate.cfm inclusion, while submitting the form through clicking "Save as draft" button.

Also the form method should be `POST`, so that form scope will be available on action page, otherwise it'll available in URL scope.

```
<cfset tx_name = "">

<cfif isDefined("form.tx_name")>
    <cfset tx_name = form.tx_name>
</cfif>

<cfif isdefined("form.Save")>
    <cfinclude template="_validate.cfm">
</cfif>

<cfif isDefined("form.tx_name")>
    <cfinclude template="_update.cfm">
</cfif>

<form name="something" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="tx_name" value="#tx_name#">
    <input type="submit" name="SaveAsDraft" value="Save as Draft">
    <input type="submit" name="Save" value="Save">
</form>
```

Comment: This should work; However, consider using `strucKeyExists()` rather than `isDefined()`. structKeyExists is more precise, has slightly better performance, and considered best practice. Usage of `isDefined` can potentially open yourself up to scope injection attacks when not used correctly. See: https://www.petefreitag.com/item/834.cfm

Answer (score 3):

I would go down the road of both buttons having the same name, but a different value. I would also use button tags so that I could have better control over the display vs the value submitted. I would then not have to deal with if the display needs change, I would not have to change the processing. Last but not least I would wrap it so that it only operates in `post`

```
 <cfscript>
 if (cgi.request_method == "post") {

     if (form.keyexists("tx_name") tx_name = form.tx_name;

     if form.SaveMode == "Save")   include "_validate.cfm";

     if (form.keyexists("tx_name") include "_update.cfm";
     }
</cfscript>

 <form name="something" method="post">
     <input type="text" name="tx_name" value="#tx_name#">
     <button type="submit" name="SaveMode" value="Save as Draft">Save As Draft</button>
     <button type="submit" name="SaveMode" value="Save">Save</button>
 </form>
```

Comment: I tried this version as well and it worked, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I use a hidden form field called `action`. On the buttons I attach an onClick to change the value of `action`. On the form's action page I read that value and determine what to do. EX:

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="save" id="action"> 
<button type="submit" class="button button-basic-green" onclick="document.getElementById('action').value='save';"><span class="fa fa-save"></span> Save</button>
<button type="submit" class="button button-basic" onclick="document.getElementById('action').value='reload';"><span class="fa fa-repeat"></span> Save & Reload</button>
<button type="submit" class="button button-basic" onclick="document.location.href='./';return false;"><span class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-left"></span> Cancel</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I tried this and it worked as well.