# Form submit not passing button name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, coldfusion

I have a form that I am trying to prevent multiple submits on:

```
<form id="autoSumForm" name="autoSumForm" method="post" action="add_ticket.cfm" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
```

The form has two save buttons:

```
<input class="saveButton" tabindex="0" type="submit" name="save2" id="save2" value="Save This Ticket" disabled="true" onclick="this.disabled=true;this.value='Please Wait...'; this.form.submit();"/>

<input class="saveCloseButton" tabindex="0" type="submit" name="save1" id="save1" value="Save and Close" disabled="true" /><!---Save and close ticket --->
```

I have this script that I am using to disable and change the value of the buttons once one is clicked.

```
<!--- Prevents submitting form twice --->
        $('#autoSumForm').submit(function()
            {
            $("input[type='submit']", this)
            .val("Please Wait...")
            .attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            return true;
        });
```

However strangely enough, when I use that script, it doesn't pass the button name to my action-page. I know that because I use an if statement to check which submit button was clicked so I can redirect properly. If I disable the script the redirect works fine but when enabled it skips right over my if statements. What would be causing that?

Here is my I redirect if statement:

```
<cfif StructKeyExists(form,"save1")>
    <!---Send user back to tech view screen --->

     <!--- Updated Ticket Lock Fields in Service_Ticket table--->
        <cfquery name="ticket_lock_update" datasource="#datasource#">
        update service_ticket
        set edit_lock=0, last_edited=<CFQUERYPARAM Value="#CreateODBCDateTime(Now())#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_TIMESTAMP">, last_edited_by=<CFQUERYPARAM Value="#techID#">
        where ticket_id= <CFQUERYPARAM Value="#form.ticket_id#">
        </cfquery>

    <cflocation url="dashboard.cfm">    
</cfif>

<cfif StructKeyExists(form,"save2")>
    <!---Save ticket and send user back to the same ticket screen --->

     <!--- Updated Ticket Lock Fields in Service_Ticket table--->
        <cfquery name="ticket_lock_update" datasource="#datasource#">
        update service_ticket
        set edit_lock=1, last_edited=<CFQUERYPARAM Value="#CreateODBCDateTime(Now())#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_TIMESTAMP">, last_edited_by=<CFQUERYPARAM Value="#techID#">
        where ticket_id= <CFQUERYPARAM Value="#form.ticket_id#">
        </cfquery>

    <cflocation url="edit_serviceticket.cfm?ticketID=#form.ticket_id#&techID=#techID#&message=2&TT=bot">    
</cfif>
```

Comment: Why would that be?

Comment: what browser are you using? i had something similar but only in safari

Comment: UPDATE: From some testing I found that if I remove the part of the script that disables the button, it works as designed. So disabling the button doesn't pass the button's id or name. Is there a different way to disable a button?

Comment: Add a hidden field to your form.  Add something to your submit function that gives it an appropriate value.  Process that field on your action page.

Comment: Thanks, that was a perfect solution. If you make that comment an answer I'll mark it as such.

Comment: *disabling the button doesn't pass the button's id or name* Read the [HTML specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2). That is the expected result. Only "successful controls" are submitted and *"...controls that are disabled cannot be successful."*

Comment: This answer will work for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43063153/2-submit-buttons-in-1-form/43077988#43077988

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a hidden field to your form. Add something to your submit function that gives it an appropriate value. Process that field on your action page.